# Display the group by with metadata in SPGridView

Tags: managed-metadata, metadata, spgridview

I have one SPGridView, on this grid, I'd like to have the group by based on the Managed Metadata column.
But the display in the Group by line will contain the TermID like below:

> Type: Testing|1e2f0ded-3e46-4bf1-94ea-8f92f5d90bb3

I'd like this like will display like:

> Type: Testing

I've already used the ItemTemplateCustom to get the label, not the whole term. But I think it didn't affect the Group by line. 
Have you any solution on this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not write `JS` code inside content editor & then get the HTML elements containing the GROUP BY text & then change it. You can use Jquery to do this

1) Get the TABLE by using

```
$("TABLE.ms-listviewtable")
```

2) Loop through all the `TBODY` tags which have `groupstring` attribute as not `null/empty`. then you get the content inside the `TD` of qualifying `TBODY` & then do JS substring & replace the proper string using

```
$("TABLE.ms-listviewtable TBODY").each(function(){
    var isHavingGroup = $(this).attr("groupstring");
    if(isHavingGroup != null || isHavingGroup != "") {     
        var requiredTD = $(this).children().find("TD");
        var existing_text = requiredTD.text();
        //Do the substring - here you split & then use the text
        requiredTD.text(new string);
    }
});
```